# NestJS Circular Dependency Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm facing a weird issue while working with NestJS modules, the error is asking me to import the same module into it. I've attached an error below.

`error`

```
- If UserRepository is a provider, is it part of the current UserService?
- If UserRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UserService?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing UserRepository */ ]
  })
```

`user.service.ts`

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>
  ) {}
}
```

`user.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  controllers: [UserController],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Comment: Does your example also import the UserModule into your AppModule ?. There are examples on the NestJS github https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/13-mongo-typeorm/src

Comment: @mh377 yes, it does

Comment: Can you also add the import statements and appmodule to your example ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, somewhere you have `UserService` added to an `imports` array. Providers **never** belong in the `imports` array and you should instead import the `UserModule` which should have the `UserService` in the `providers` and `exports` array.